# Why do we use shim coils in MRI scan machine?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Currently, I am studing about MRI machines. I had come across one article related to the working of MRI machines in which I understood the working of Supercooled magnet, gradient coil, and RF coils but I didn't understand the use of Shims coils. Also please explain all coil usage in detail.
[image]

Comment: In a mechanical context, what are shims used for? Why would you want 'shim' magnets if you want a precise, aligned magnetic field?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(magnetism)